# How to stop and start Jenkins on Mac

Tags: macos, jenkins

I installed Jenkins on my Mac local machine. It is running and working fine. What is the right way to stop and start the server from terminal?

Answer (score 40):

You might be able to use launchctl for starting and stopping Jenkins.

Start

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Stop

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.jenkins-ci.plist
```

Comment: if you have installed using brew then use this command "brew services start jenkins-lts" replace lts with any version you have installed